# Private TeamCity Nuget doesn't add assembly reference

Tags: c#, nuget, teamcity, nuget-package

I have 1 class library with 1 public class in it, for testing purposes.  I have a step in TeamCity to build the solution and I use the "NuGet Pack" step to drop it into the TeamCity private NuGet repository, it all builds fine.

I then created a console app and using NuGet, I can see my project and I can add it, it downloads the project, but it doesn't add the project reference.

The nuspec file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Andrew.Test</id>
    <version>1.0.1.0</version>
    <title>Andrew.Test</title>
    <authors>Andrew</authors>
    <owners>Andrew</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright ©  2016</copyright>
    <dependencies />
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I'm only new to creating NuGet packages, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards,

Andrew

Comment: Please show how the console app build is configured in TeamCity and the relevant parts of the TeamCity build log.

Comment: Under General Settings I have for "artifact paths" - "packages\*.nupkg".   Under NuGet Pack, I have it using NuGet 3.3.0 and I specify my csproj file. Under Output Directory I have "packages" and "Clean output directory" and "Publish created packages to build artifacts" ticked

Comment: When you add the nuget package to console app, what's the content of the packages.config? Is the nuget package downloaded from the server to your packages folder? What's inside the folder? Have you tried unzipping the nupkg file? Is the DLL inside it?

Comment: The nupkg file is in the packages folder, the packages.config has reference to the package, but for some reason it's just not hooking up the DLL in the reference to the console app.  I suspect there is a issue with the structure of my class library because I moved on and manually hooked it up and other class libraries work as expected.  I just haven't had time to go back to compare project files for now, but keen to know if there is anything special required from a project file for a NuGet package?

Comment: Do your assemblies exist in packages\<YourPackage>.<YourVersion>\lib\<framework>\, e.g. packages\Andrew.Test.1.0.1.0\lib\net45?

Comment: I started this assembly off from the default class library template in VS2015 and added some assembly info (if this helps)

Comment: So the plot thickens, I had some time over the weekend and setup a basic class library at home with VS2015 (not SP1) and it worked first go.  As it took ages to install quite a few updates, I've shelved this for another time.  My plan of attack next is to create a class library again (this time with SP1) and see what happens.  If it doesn't work under this environment, I'll do a file compare of the first project file and see what the difference is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I'm not sure why this was happening.  I changed the name of the assembly, let it build and drop the newly named assembly in the private Teamcity NuGet repository and then installed it and it attached the new assembly as expected without changing any code.  I hope this helps someone else in future as this took a lot of time out of my days